# Update column by parsing another column with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this table and data in my database:

**tblPhotos**

```
ID | Title | Description
------------------------------
1 | NULL | Some data - Title 123 - Subtitle - Photographer: John Doe
2 | NULL | Some data - Photographer: Jane Doe
3 | NULL | Some data - Title 345 - Photographer: John Doe Jr
```

The data in the `Description` column comes in two formats:

```
{GARBAGE DATA} - {TITLE DATA} - Photographer: ..., or
{GARBAGE DATA} - Photographer: ...
```

Basically, I have thousands of rows, where the `Title` column is empty. I need to somehow pull it out of the `Description` column.

The `Title` exists between the first dash and the and the last dash of the `Description` column. Here's what the data should look like:

**tblPhotos**

```
ID | Title                | Description
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | Title 123 - Subtitle | Some data - Title 123 - Subtitle - Photographer: John Doe
 2 | NULL                 | Some data - Photographer: Jane Doe
 3 | Title 345            | Some data - Title 345 - Photographer: John Doe Jr
```

How can I make a script that will parse a column, and update another column with that parsed data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location of the first dash is easy: `CHARINDEX('-', Description)`. The location of the second dash is easy, too, but you want the location of the *last* dash. That's a bit harder because you have to reverse the string to get it: `LEN(Description) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Description))`. To get the stuff in between you need to find the length by subtracting the two positions:

`SUBSTRING(Description, CHARINDEX('-', Description) + 1, LEN(Description) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Description))) - CHARINDEX('-', Description)`

Putting it all together you get:

```
UPDATE tblPhotos
SET Title = RTRIM(LTRIM(
            SUBSTRING(Description,
                      CHARINDEX('-', Description) + 1,
                      LEN(Description) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Description))
                                       - CHARINDEX('-', Description))))
WHERE Title IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

Try someting like this:

```
update tblPhotos
    set title = substring(description, charindex('-', description)+1,
                          (charindex('-', description, charindex('-', description) + 1) -
                           charindex('-', description)
                          )-1
                         )
    where title is null and description like '%-%-%'
```

You might need to trim spaces from the title.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE p
SET Title = SUBSTRING(p.Description, s.StartPos, e.EndPos - s.StartPos)
FROM tblPhotos p
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (PATINDEX('% - % - %:%', p.Description) + 3) ) s (StartPos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CHARINDEX(' - ', p.Description, s.StartPos))) e (EndPos)
WHERE p.Description LIKE '% - % - %:%'
;
```

`PATINDEX` would return the position of the first argument's first non-mask character, so the `PATINDEX` in the above query would return the position of the first  `-`  (space, hyphen, space) entry. Adding 3 to that value and using the result as the starting position, the `CHARINDEX`, in its turn, returns the position of the second  `-`  entry, and that is aliased as the end position. The two values are then used by the `SUBSTRING` function to extract the title.

SQL Fiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2dd9/3

References:

- [`PATINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)
- [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)